# how to add a mask AND a background to canvas element

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to make an image masked by a png with a background image. It works fine when I put the masked image only but if I add a background image the front image is not masked anymore

```
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var bg = new Image();
  var front = new Image();
  var mask = new Image();

  bg.src = 'img/background.jpg';

  bg.onload = function() {
    front.src = "img/tobemasked.jpg";
  };

  front.onload = function() {
    mask.src = "img/mask.png";
  }

  mask.onload = function() {
    display();
  }

  function display() {
    context.drawImage(bg, 0, 0); // it works if i remove this line
    context.drawImage(tmpMask, 0, 0);
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
    context.drawImage(front, 0, 0);
  }
</script>
```

I guess this is a quite common problem but I couldn't find anything related on the web.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "source-in" operation you are using to mask the front image is defined here http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#gcop-source-in like this:

> Display the source image wherever both the source image and
>   destination image are opaque. Display transparency elsewhere.

Without drawing the background image, the destination image consists of only your mask and supposedly has transparent pixels. The front image will be displayed only where the mask is opaque. I understand that this is what you want.

However, after you have also drawn the background image, there are supposedly no transparent pixels in the destination image, it's totally opaque, and when you draw the front image, all parts of it will be displayed.

This would accomplish what I think you are trying to do:

```
context.drawImage(mask, 0, 0);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
context.drawImage(front, 0, 0);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
context.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
```

The front image is masked first. After that there still are transparent pixels. The background image gets drawn on the transparent area with "destination-atop" option (see previous link).

I think that's the simplest method. Some other options are to use multiple canvas elements on top of each others to create layers or use some javascript library that makes it possible to use layers with canvas.

Comment: THANK YOU !
This is exactly what i needed. You saved me hours of work because I was far from figuring out how the globalCompositeOperation was working but now it's clear to my mind :)